# lack of understanding about an example presented in Engel's book

Tags: geometry

> Let $n ≥ 5$. Show that, among the ${s_n}$ space parts, there
> are at least $ {2n-3\over 4} $ tetrahedra
> ; where ${s_n}$ denotes the number of parts the space is divided by $n$ planes in general position

what I didn't understand is the following

> Interpretation of the numerator of the fraction $ {2n-3\over 4} $ : On each of the n planes rest at least two tetrahedra. Only one tetrahedron need rest on each of three exceptional planes.

could someone explain this assertion?(in particular the very last part).